# Error when adding WMS layer to GeoNetwork Map

Tags: wms, geonetwork

I am setting up local stack of pgadmin4 (v2), geoserver (2.12.1) and geonetwork (3.4)(on tomcat 9).

I've been testing to see if the layers i've uploaded to pgadmin and added to geoserver work, and they do. I can easily add them as a wms service with QGIS.

However, I am trying to add them also to map of geonetwork, and it doesn't seem to work. No matter which layer I use, it won't work. Even other WMS services that I know work.

I get this error:

[image: error message]

> Something went wrong while loading tile 'http://localhost:8080/geoserve ...' for layer 'river_ciliwung[3857]'.

Very strange, because geonetork is able to do a WMSrequest  `GetCapabilities` no problem.

See picture, it retrieves all the layers:

[image: get capabilities request]

furthermore, I used chrome (f12) to inspect the requests, and this is also very strange. GeoNetwork does a bunch of requests and they all get canceled.

[image]

How do I add a wms map layer to the geonetwork map?

Comment: Maybe your WMS layer doesn't support the CRS GN map is using...

Comment: good point...what is the CRS GeoNet is using?

Comment: I found it, it has epsg:3857. So that can't be the case.

Comment: Is there some additional information i could provide? I am clueless, I have exhausted online documentation, so any tips would be great.

Comment: Any error in the Javascript console? Have you tried with other browsers?

Comment: You can try this. In the GUI settings page, https://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/admin.console#/settings/ui, uncheck the option_Export map as image_ to make Openlayers use the classic `<img src="..." >` for the tiles instead of the `<canvas>` element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72759/discussion-between-juanluisrp-and-j-a-cado).

Comment: I have the same problem I can't see the WMS and I uncheck the box and the problem persists. Help Me!! Thank's you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login as an admin, go to the admin console -> *Settings* -> *User interface* tab and uncheck the box *Export map as image* ( http://example.com/geonetwork/srv/eng/admin.console#/settings/ui).

[image: Export map as image option disabled]
This will make GN use the classic `<img src="...">` for rendering the map instead of using a `<canvas>` element that is blocked by the browser if the WMS images don't come with the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).