# Error WMS GeoNetwork 3.4

Tags: wms, geonetwork, geoportal

I have a problem with external WMS in GeoNetwork 3.4 and GeoNetwork 3.4.1 (Development Release). I see others questions in this forum ([Error when adding WMS layer to GeoNetwork Map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270293/error-when-adding-wms-layer-to-geonetwork-map)) and it doesn't solve my problem.

[image]

I can't see the WMS. I uncheck the box and the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the map you are trying to add

Comment: This is a example http://land.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Forest/ForestFragmentationCarpathians2015/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GeoNetwork 3.4.1.0 I am able to add your example WMS layer by specifying just the endpoint:

`http://land.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Forest/ForestFragmentationCarpathians2015/MapServer/WMSServer?`

As below:

[image: WMS layer in GeoNetwork 3.4.1.0]

I had to untick the `Export map as image` option, and I also don't have the `Allow 3D mode` selected.

Comment: Great!!! the problem was Allow 3D mode selected. Thank´s you!!!